# ora-01036 illegal variable name/number c#

Tags: c#, oracle

help me please

I get an error when fetching data for the date range

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT (select dep_title from hr.departments dp where dp.dep_id = d.dep_id) as title,    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM esd.DOCUMENTS T");
       sb.Append("WHERE T.DEP_ID = D.DEP_ID");
       sb.Append("and t.systarix between");
       sb.Append("to_date(':FROM_DATE', 'MM.DD.YYYY') And");
       sb.Append("to_date(':TO_DATE', 'MM.DD.YYYY')) AS SAY");
       sb.Append("FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D");


       command.CommandText = sb.ToString();

       command.Parameters.Add("FROM_DATE", OracleType.VarChar);
       command.Parameters["FROM_DATE"].Value = DE_from.DateTime.Date;
       command.Parameters.Add("TO_DATE", OracleType.VarChar);
       command.Parameters["TO_DATE"].Value = DE_to.DateTime.Date;


       dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

       gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
```

**Error**

> ora-01036 illegal variable name/number

Comment: Do not add single quotes around the parameters name. They become literal strings in that way

Comment: the problem initially that I see is in your `StringBuilder code` you need to add spaces `" "` at the end of every quoted string if you were to use the debugger and step thru the code and evaluate `sb in the QuickWatch` you will see the issue immediately.

Comment: Steve, MethodMan thank you very much :)

Comment: @NursultanKHalilov you're welcom, if you are not familiar with the debugger, there are lots of tutorials / documentation on C# MSDN official site that walk you through step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your Query looks like also how come you do not close the opening `(` in your Sub Select. I would recommend reading up on some basic Sql Selects. Oracle has very good documentation in regards to Syntax.

Also read up on how to properly construct / format a `Sub-Query`

look at the fields in the select I formatted it so you can see your original query you build using StringBuilder.

```
SELECT 
(
    select dep_title from hr.departments dp where dp.dep_id = d.dep_id) as title,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM esd.DOCUMENTS TWHERE T.DEP_ID = D.DEP_IDand t.systarix 
        betweento_date(':FROM_DATE', 'MM.DD.YYYY') Andto_date(':TO_DATE', 'MM.DD.YYYY')
    ) AS SAYFROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D
```

Your errors in right off the bat because of the spacing " " you didn't add are

**TWHERE** this should  be T WHERE

**D.DEP_IDand t.systarix** this should be D.DEP_ID and t.systarix

**betweento_date** this should be between to_date

**AS SAYFROM** this should be AS SAY FROM

I would suggest / recommend creating your Select Query's in the Oracle Developer and executing them first. From there once you get the query working, convert the query into a Stored Procedure.